# Can API Gateway be setup to have sticky sessions for canary deployments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, canary-deployment

If a user gets sent to the canary deployment, is it possible to ensure that all subsequent requests from that user also go to the canary deployment? From my preliminary testing API Gateway doesn't seem to do that by default, so is there a way to set it up so they do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback! We don't support sticky sessions unfortunately. I will add an item to our backlog for this feature.